# Scala structural type as function type param

Tags: scala, duck-typing, structural-typing

I want to create some "general adder" function, which would work for all types which have support for "+" operation.
I have tried structural typing as function type param, but this not compile:

```
def f[T <: { def +(x: T): T} ](a: T, b: T): T = a + b

error: Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement
```

Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: I believe neither Int, nor String has + methods. Probably implicit conversions can help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a workaround for this issue, other than for example using type classes. You'll need an implicit conversions for the types you want to handle, though.

The Scala language specification says

> Within a method declaration in a structural refinement, the type of
>   any value parameter may only refer to type parameters or abstract
>   types that are contained inside the refinement. That is, it must refer
>   either to a type parameter of the method itself, or to a type
>   definition within the refinement. This restriction does not apply to
>   the function’s result type.

Which is why you get the error.

Example implementation could look like this

```
trait AddLike[T] {
  def +(x: T): T
}

def f[T <% AddLike[T]](a: T, b: T): T = a + b

implicit def num2AddLike[T](a: T)(implicit ev: Numeric[T]) = new AddLike[T] { def +(b: T) = ev.plus(a, b) }
implicit def str2AddLike(a: String) = new AddLike[String] { def +(b: String) = a + b }

f(1, 2)
f("one", "two")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way in Scala to create a generic function instance that can automatically handle all types that can be added. However, in Scala source code, that function can be written `_ + _`, and in some situations the types will be inferred.

```
def triple[T](value: T)(add: (T, T) => T): T = add(add(value, value), value)

triple(10)(_ + _)
triple("w")(_ + _)

def tripler[T](add: (T, T) => T): T => T = (value: T) => triple(value)(add)

val tripleDouble: Double => Double = tripler(_ + _)
tripleDouble(3.2)
```

Unfortunately, there are many such situations where you would like the types to be inferred, and they won't be.